# Incorrect rendering of open brackets in JEditorPane

Tags: java, macos, swing, jeditorpane

I have a NetBeans platform application with a groovy editor that is created as follows

```
JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
EditorKit kit = CloneableEditorSupport.getEditorKit("text/x-groovy");
editorPane.setEditorKit(kit);
```

A client logged a bug (anonymously) that certain characters in the editor are not rendered correctly in OS X 10.7.5 (Lion) and supplied a screenshot.

It looks like only the left half of the '(' and '{' characters are rendered and not the right half, but the rest of the characters (in the screenshot) renders fine.

A snippet of the screenshot showing a bunch of open and close round brackets is given below.

[image]

So far I have been unable to reproduce the issue. I'm hoping someone who has can point me in the right direction.

Has anyone else seen something similar?

Comment: [public final void setContentType(String type)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setContentType%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I managed to test the app on an OS X Lion machine and it looks like it always happens on Lion (but not on Leopard). I tried `editorPane.setContentType("text/x-groovy; charset=UTF-8")` instead of `editorPane.setEditorKit(kit)` but it had no effect, the brackets are still rendered incorrectly.

Comment: post an SSCCE with all above mentioned (better could be delete this post and to create a new one)